# Match 2 columns from 2 different workbooks, if no match then put 0 in another column?

Tags: vba, excel

I just need a little bit of help with this code. I just about have it but not quite.

I need to match 2 different columns in 2 different workbooks. I need to match column b (sku) on workbook datafeed.xlsx to workbook result.xlsx on column b (sku), as shown in the code.
If no match from result.xlsx from workgroup datafeed.xlsx then I need it to put a number 0 in column/row ab2 which is offset to column 26 from b2.

I know in a lookup table i could use ISNA but i couldn't even get that to work. I tried different things but no luck. I am definately doing something wrong because it doesn't work and help would be appreciated.

This is my code below:

```
    Set w3 = Workbooks("datafeed.xlsx").Sheets("datafeed")    Set w4 = Workbooks("result.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet 1")

    For Each z In w3.Range("b2", w3.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    XR = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    XR = Application.Match(z, w4.Columns("b"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If XR <> 0 Then w4.Range("AB2" & XR).Value = z.Offset(, 11)

    Next z
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you lookup values in column B of your source sheet in column B of your target sheet. If the target sheet contains the value (/not) you want a 1/0 written to column AB.

The code below reads the two columns into arrays and loops through them comparing the two. A results array of same length is created and a 1/0 is writen to it when the item is found/not found. In the end the array is pasted to column AB

```
Sub test()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim compare1 As Variant, compare2 As Variant, result As Variant

    Set wbSource = Workbooks("datafeed.xlsx")
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks("result.xlsx")
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("datafeed")
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet 1")

    compare1 = wsSource.Range("B2", wsSource.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    compare2 = wsTarget.Range("B2", wsTarget.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    ReDim result(LBound(compare1), UBound(compare1))

    For i = LBound(compare1) To UBound(compare1)
        found = False
        For j = LBound(compare2) To UBound(compare2)
            If compare1(i) = compare2(j) Then
                result(i) = 1
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If found = False Then
            result(i) = 0
        End If
    Next i
    wsSource.Range(Cells(2, 28), Cells(UBound(result) + 1, 28)) = Results

End Sub
```

Comment: on set wstarget = wbtargetsheets("Sheet 1") It comes up with an error. But then i changed it to wbtarget.Sheets("Sheet 1"). I think that fixed that error but now i have another error that says Compile error: For without Next. I am assuming it to be Next I because J has Next J?

Comment: Thank you. I changed it. There was a `Next i` missing

Comment: I don't know why but i get a subscript out of range on the code If compare1(i) = compare2(j) Then ?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. What is the value of i and j when it runs out of bound and what is the value of ubound(compare1) and ubound(compare2)?

Comment: i = 1 = LBound (compare1)=1 To UBound (compare1) = 4464, For J = 1 = LBound (compare2) = 1 To UBound (compare2)=2037, If compare1 (I)  = <subscript out of range> = compare2 (j) Then <subscript out of range> i =1 and j=1

Comment: can you upload examples of the two files?

Comment: I couldn't figure a way to upload it to this forum so i linked it. I hope linking is okay in the rules.